# Ooyala video player (iOS): how to ALWAYS hide video control?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ooyala

I use Ooyala video player in my project, and I need to have my own video control, so I need a way to hind its built-in video control, I found that the `OOOoyalaPlayerViewController` has method `showControls`, but the control appears when you tap the video, so is there a way to explicitly hide the controls? I've tried subclassing OOOoyalaPlayerViewController and overwrite `showControls` to do nothing but it did not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating custom controls, you probably want to use an OOOoyalaPlayer directly versus going through the OOOoyalaPlayerViewController- all the viewcontroller does is add controls on top of the player.

If you must use an OOOoyalaPlayerViewController, try subclassing OOControlsViewController and overwriting - (void)onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender.  The source for this is bundled with our SDK.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nice to see someone from Ooyala responding, can you also have a look at this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850087/ooyala-player-ios-how-to-start-in-full-screen, thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a way to hide only the 'zoom' button (for switching to fullscreen mode) in inline mode?

Comment: you would need to subclass OOInlineControlsView

Comment: thanks, then is there a property I can set on OOOoyalaPalyerViewController for the inline control view?

Comment: Sorry @chrisl I could not find OOInlineControlsView in header files.

Comment: its included in the controls source bundled with the SDK.