# Ooyala player (iOS): how to start in full screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ooyala

I am using Ooyala player in my project, the project used to use MPMoviePlayer, where we just change the view's size to make it fullscreen or not fullscreen, but Ooyala player seems to maintain its own fullscreen/inline mode by using another modal view controller when switched to full screen, this creates a lot of problem as the current view controller's `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` will be called when the modal VC is presented, so is there a way to start with full screen directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the constructors for OOOoyalaPlayerViewController that has the controlType param.

Comment: Hi, did you find some straight solution other than OOOoyalaPlayerViewController.